# Wget not working

Tags: wget

wget is not working properly on my debian server.

if I wget http://www.google.com, it says it cannot resolve the host, when I ping google.com, I receive a successful pong and when I wget http://www.debian.org it works.

I cannot wget anything else than debian.org ... pretty weird.

Comment: How are you using wget ?

Comment: Can you add in the output of `wget -O /dev/null -d http://www.google.com`

Comment: root@dragon:/etc# wget -O /dev/null -d http://www.google.com      #RETURN#  
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.12 on linux-gnu.     #RETURN#

--2011-09-27 13:18:55--  http://www.google.com/     #RETURN#
Resolving www.google.com... failed: Name or service not known.     #return#
wget: unable to resolve host address `www.google.com'     #return#
root@dragon:/etc#

Comment: how does it help ? (added #RETURN# because serverfault doesn't allow lines return)

Comment: wget IP_OF_GOOGLE works tho... so I really don't know what's the problem

Answer (score 2):

Check your DNS `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, and the table lookup for host names `cat /etc/hosts`. Try changing to Google's DNS:

```
echo "8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
echo "8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```